# Rails routes won't show the name of the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I added a route in routes.rb:

```
  match 'notifications/:id/mark_as_read' => 'notifications#mark_as_read', :via => :post
```

mark_as_read is the only action in notifications controller, and that is the only route for notifications

when I should the routes I see

```
 POST    /notifications/:id/mark_as_read(.:format)   notifications#mark_as_read
```

I don't know how to get to it, since it doesn't list as something like `notifications_mark_as_read_path`

did I do something wrong when I added the route, or can I name the route somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it..

need to name the route.. with `:as => 'my_route_name'`